# Unsure why Traceback being generated using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, traceback

I am using Python.org version 2.7 64 bit on Windows 64 bit. I have the following Scrapy code:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
import re


class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "wiki"

    allowed_domains = ["wiki.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miroslav_Klose"]


    def parse(self, response):
        titles = response.selector.xpath("normalize-space(//title)")
        for titles in titles:

            body = response.xpath("//p").extract()
            body2 = "".join(body)

            print remove_tags(body2).encode('utf-8')

execute(['scrapy','crawl','wiki'])
```

This produces a scraped output in the Python IDLE as expected when run using F5, however it also produces the following Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\mrscrap\mrscrap\spiders\test.py", line 32, in <module>
    execute(['scrapy','crawl','wiki'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 143, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 89, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 150, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\commands\crawl.py", line 57, in run
    crawler = self.crawler_process.create_crawler()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 87, in create_crawler
    self.crawlers[name] = Crawler(self.settings)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.spiders = spman_cls.from_crawler(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermanager.py", line 35, in from_crawler
    sm = cls.from_settings(crawler.settings)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermanager.py", line 31, in from_settings
    return cls(settings.getlist('SPIDER_MODULES'))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermanager.py", line 22, in __init__
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 68, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\mrscrap\mrscrap\spiders\test.py", line 32, in <module>
    execute(['scrapy','crawl','wiki'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 144, in execute
    sys.exit(cmd.exitcode)
SystemExit: 0
```

I'm still fairly new to Python, but I understand Traceback's are caused by errors, however in this instance I'm not sure what error this is trying to tell me about. Can anyone tell me what the error is and/or how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you run the spider from the command line using `scrapy crawl` or `scrapy runspider`?

Comment: If the code produced what you wanted I would not worry too much about it, idle is not the greatest for running code. You should get yourself set up with Ipython, it makes a lot of tasks very easy.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ok, i will have a look at that. learning about all the thinks that go around python like alpha and beta releases, pip, pypi, non pypi .exe files, binaries etc have been more challenging for me than learning the syntax. im a SAS developer by trade so importing code modules is not a core part of the language

Comment: @alecxe i was running it via command line initially, but my ultimate aim is to have something that i can schedule to scrape stuff for me and i wasnt sure whether command line was the best way of doing that via a batch file or not...

Comment: @user3045351 you can [run scrapy from script](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script). You can use [`scrapyd`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/scrapyd.html) that would automatically run your spiders on demand or on schedule.

Comment: I think using windows is a probably a bit more of a pain when it comes to Python also but definitely get yourself going with Ipython